# no se ven las imagenes localhost

Tags: html, html5

he estado haciendo una aplicación web con html en visual studio code, lo que pasa es que cuando escribo en el navegador localhost para ver como esta quedando se ve todo perfecto pero no se visualizan las imágenes (cabe aclarar que tengo bien las rutas y todo) la cosa esque hace poco instale la extension live server para ir viendo de mejor manere como va quedando mi web y me di cuenta de que al abrir la web con esa extension se ven las imagenes perfectas del proyecto pero en vez de decir localhost sale los siguientes numeros 127.0.0.1, no se que podria estar haciendo mal o que es diferente en ese sentido.

les dejo una foto de como tengo las carpetas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les proporciono mi codigo:

```
<div class="contenedor">
<div class="Formulario" id="Formulario">
  <div class="cuadro_tramites">
    <div class="cuadro_logo" id="cuadro_logo">
      <img src="imagenes/logomuni.png" width="100" height="80">
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor_tramites">
      <h3 class="bienvenidx">Bienvenid@</h3>
      <h4 class="tramitx">Selecciona el tramite que deseas:</h4>
      <div class="cuadro-scroll">
        <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
          <form action="https://home.municipalidadgorbea.cl/archivos/3118">
            <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Permiso de circulacion</label>
            <hr>
            <img class="i_pcirculacion" src="imagenes/coche.png" width="150px" height="150px">
            <button class="boton2" type="submit" value="Pagar aqui">Pagar aqui</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
          <form action="https://www.sem.gob.cl/pago/buscar.php?pago_id=4&inst_id=69191200&setiframe=0">
            <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Pago derechos de aseo</label>
            <hr>
            <img class="i_pago_derechos_aseo" src="imagenes/envase.png" width="150px" height="150px">
            <button class="boton2" type="submit" value="pagar aqui">Pagar aqui</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
          <form action="http://localhost:5500/tramitesDOM">
            <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Tramites departamentos de obras</label>
            <hr>
            <img class="i_Tramites_DOM" src="imagenes/en-construccion.png" width="150px" height="150px">
            <button class="boton2" type="submit" value="pagar aqui">Revisar aqui</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
          <form action="https://rsh.ministeriodesarrollosocial.gob.cl/portada">
            <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Registro social de hogares</label>
            <hr>
            <img class="i_Registro_SH" src="imagenes/familia.png" width="150px" height="150px">
            <button class="boton2" type="submit" value="pagar aqui">Revisar aqui</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="circulos">
    <table class="tabla">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="http://localhost:5500/Eventos"><button class="linea"><img class="i_Eventos" src="imagenes/calendario.png"></button></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="https://www.portaltransparencia.cl/PortalPdT/web/guest/directorio-de-organismos-regulados?p_p_id=pdtorganismos_WAR_pdtorganismosportlet&orgcode=e1c4b38162d39"><button class="linea"><img class="i_solicitar_info" src="imagenes/informacion.png"></button></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="https://www.leylobby.gob.cl/instituciones/MU099"><button class="linea"><img class="i_solicitar_audiencia" src="imagenes/hacer-clic.png"></button></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/index4.html"><button class="linea"><img class="i_conoce_losP" src="imagenes/usuario.png"></button></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p class="parrafo">Eventos</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p class="parrafo">Solicitar informacion</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p class="parrafo">Solicitar audiencia</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p class="parrafo">Conoce los progrmas</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="cuadro_directo">
    <h3>Gorbea en vivo:</h3>
    <h4>
      <p class="p_envivo">En vivo ahora </p>
    </h4>
    <iframe width="100%" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ceqgwo7U28Y" title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="botones_espacio">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="botones_fixed">
    <button class="cuadrado1">
      <a class="label2" href="tel:452972000">Llamanos</a>
    </button>
    <form action="http://localhost:5500/FormContacto">
      <button class="cuadrado2">
        Envianos un mensaje
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: proporciona el código de las etiquetas para las imágenes.  utilizas servidor o directamente abres la pagina?

Comment: tienes algun host agregado en el archivo host de windows

Comment: 127.0.0.1 es localhost, eso no debe preocuparte (seguramente en tu archivo c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts de windows tienes esa correspondencia y por eso te lo cambia, pero es lo mismo y no debes ni cambiarlo ni preocuparte).

Comment: uso xamp y abro la pagina usando localhost:5000/mipagina pero de esa manera no se ven las imagenes, puse mi codigo para que puedan verlo, pero por ejemplo en "imagenes/logomuni" lo pongo asi por que tengo una carpeta llamada imagenes dentro de la carpeta raiz del proyecto, en teoria esta todo bien en ese sentido, pero cuano lo abro con la extension si se me ven las imagenes y se me cambia la ruta por 127.0.0.1:5000/mi pagina :c

Comment: O sea, ¿tienes dos servidores en marcha en el mismo puerto?  Lo digo por lo del xamp, que corre aparte del live server... Prueba cerrando el xamp y solo con el live server a ver que ocurre.

Comment: siguen sin verse, pero con la extensión si se ven, debe ser algo de los puertos creo yo pero no se que podrá ser no soy muy entendido en el tema